# Ionic1 CFBundleIconName Info.plist missing?

Tags: ionic-framework

I found already lots of answers regarding the 'missing CFBundleIconName' issue, but not how to fix it for ionic projects. That needs to be configured in their `config.xml`, but how, what and where? It's an ionic version 1 project. Upgrading to v2 is not an answer nor solution.

> Missing Info.plist value - A value for the Info.plist key
>   CFBundleIconName is missing in the bundle 'foo.bar.sheep'. Apps that
>   provide icons in the asset catalog must also provide this Info.plist
>   key

Comment: Are you using any plugin?

Comment: @PareshGami phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner, cordova-plugin-media-capture and ordova-plugin-image-picker; is that a conflict? thought a missing assets library is the issue?

Comment: That is issue when you ask for permission for access camera you can see dialog so for that you have message for permission

Comment: No, that's not the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I uploaded the IPA file created with robovm

here is how I solve it :

Modify your iOS project's "Info.plist.xml" file.
Under "dict" node, add like this:

[image]